# Where in this markup would I insert <script> tags?

Tags: asp.net

Here is the markup that I have:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="AddSale.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Add New Sale
    </h2>
    <p>
Please use the buttons and controls below to add a new sale for this lot to the dealership's database.
        </p>
    <div style="height: 180px; width: 300px"> 
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block" Text="Salesperson:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" style="float:right; margin:0 auto; display:inline-block"></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <br />

         <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block" Text="VIN:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" style="float:right; margin:0 auto; display:inline-block"></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" style="margin:0 auto; display:inline-block" Text="Sale Price:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="test" runat="server" style="float:right; margin:0 auto; display:inline-block"></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" style="display:inline-block" Text="MSRP:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" style="float:right; display:inline-block;"></asp:TextBox>

        <br />
        <br />

        <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" style=" display:inline-block;" Text="Commission Rate:"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" style="float:right; display:inline-block;"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
        <br />

    </div>
    <p>
        <asp:Button ID="btntest" runat="server" Text="Add Record"/>
    </p>

    </asp:Content>
```

I can't seem to figure out how I would add a `<script>` tag in the markup, everything I try gives me an error.

I want to add a script that includes a function that will reject empty or badly-written boxes using regex. I notice that I don't have `<html>` or `<head>` or `<body>` tags on my code. Will I use those? Are those necessary at all? Where would I add it on here? By the way, this is not the master page.

Comment: You presumably do have `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags on your master page, which gets merged with the content page when it's delivered to the client. Research master pages if you have any confusion about that. And depending on where your `ContentPlaceHolder` elements are on the server, you can probably add your scripts to the `<head>` by putting them in the correct `Content` block. As to where you *should* put them, see [Where is the best place to put <script> tags in HTML markup?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup).

Comment: What is the Error you are getting?

Comment: @f0s9adf7as8df2 Wondering if the answer below helps you. I see you are new to the site. It is good form here accept and vote up answers that help solve you issue. If you issue is not solved, please leave a comment and I will help further.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the javascript function on this page, try adding the `script` tag inside of your `HeadContent` tag to get yourself started.

If you put the script in the master page, then that script will load and be available on every page that uses that master page.

It should be noted that many prefer their JavaScript in a separate file which you can then reference with a `link` tag within the `head` tag. Mason's link in his comment provides good information.